# How to foreach all Woocommerce product images

Tags: woocommerce

I wanna create my custom product gallery, and I need to loop through all images featured image and attachment images.
I need to create array contains featured image and attachment images.
I need the code to be like that.

```
foreach( $images as $image_src_url ) 
{
  echo '<img src="'.$image_src_url.'">';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
global $product;

$attachment_ids  = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
$image_urls      = array();
$image_id        = $product->get_image_id();
if ( $image_id ) {
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, 'full' );

    $image_urls[ 0 ] = $image_url;
}

foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
    $image_urls[] = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
}

foreach ( $image_urls as $image_src_url ) {
    echo '<img src="' . $image_src_url . '">';
}
?>
```

Try this code snippet.

Comment: This snippet gets product attachments "Product Gallery" only. I need to include Featured Image "Product Image" As well

Comment: $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); // for featured image

Comment: How to merge featured image and attachment images in one array and foreach this array to get all product images (featured + attachment)?

Comment: @mujuonly, I added your answer, I am getting the product gallery images but not getting the feature images and i need both

Comment: $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

   $image_urls = array();

   if ( $product->get_image_id() ) {
    $image_urls[ 0 ] = wp_get_attachment_url( $product->get_image_id() );
   }

   foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
    $image_urls[] = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
   }

Comment: but how to display the image? I tried    echo '<img src="'.$image_urls.'"alt="">';

Comment: @mujuonly, Please help me in this

Comment: @mujuonly, Yes, this time it's working. Thanks for the help. Upvote from my side.

Comment: can you help me out with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65843843/how-to-use-the-custom-plugin-with-the-priority-order-number