# How to use the custom plugin with the priority order number?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am learning WooCommerce development. I installed the pin checker plugin and that displays above the add to cart button. Screenshot here https://prnt.sc/xftmpn

Now I have displayed the paragraph below of the pin checker and I used the below code but it's displaying above the pin checker.

```
function action_woocommerce_single_product_pinchecker_content() {
    echo "<span>Please enter PIN code to check delivery time & other more</span>";
}
 add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_single_product_pinchecker_content', 28, 0 );
```

I can do it with jQuery and it's working but I don't want to do it with jQuery.

```
$('.pin_div').append("<span>Please enter PIN code to check delivery time & other more</span>");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'mujuonly_before_add_to_cart_btn' );

function mujuonly_before_add_to_cart_btn() {
    echo "<span>" . __( 'Please enter PIN code to check delivery time & other more<', 'woocommerce' ) . "/span>";
}
```

Comment: I tried but it's displaying before the Product description

Comment: Try changing priority 15 to  999 0r 6

Comment: I tried 6 but not working then I tried 29 then I am getting like this https://prnt.sc/xg0j5h and then I tried 30 then I am getting like this https://prnt.sc/xg0z4p    I have to show below the pin code checker

Comment: Please share the pincode checker code - there would be some hook to print in between

Comment: How can I get that? I am using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/check-pincodezipcode-for-shipping-woocommerce/

Comment: It's displaying below the cart. It should be displayed between the pin checker and add to the cart.

Comment: Can you help me out with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65897369/how-to-separate-the-login-and-register-page-and-access-using-shortcode